# merging/summing dictionaries in dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, python-3.5

Python 3.5

I have a dictionary which has mutiple dictionaries which has multiple dictionaries. It looks like this (simplified):

```
database = {'HIV' : {'gene1' : {'val': 2, 'thr' : 4, 'met' : 5}, 
                  'gene2' : {'val': 3, 'thr' : 6, 'met' : 7}},
           'HIV2' : {'gene1' : {'val': 4, 'thr' : 1, 'met' : 6}, 
                   'gene2' : {'val': 7, 'thr' : 9, 'met' : 8}}
           }
```

Obviously I have more of everything.
I want all the genes to be merged (in a new dictionary, so it would look like:

```
database2 = {'HIV' : {'genes' : {'val': 5, 'thr' : 10, 'met' : 12}},
           'HIV2' : {'genes' : {'val': 11, 'thr' : 10, 'met' : 14}}
           }
```

It might be a messy way of storing values, but it's what I have to work with.
How can I sum up all the values for all the genes for each virus (e.g. HIV, HIV2 etc)?

Comment: Create a function `f` which has as input `{'gene1' : {'val': 2, 'thr' : 4, 'met' : 5}, 'gene2' : {'val': 3, 'thr' : 6, 'met' : 7}}` and returns `{'genes' : {'val': 5, 'thr' : 10, 'met' : 12}}`. Now apply dictionary comprehension: `{k: f(v) for k, v in database.items()}`. ------------- Or use pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Counter` to sum up the elements and then add the result (either a counter or its underlying dictionary) into the dictionary. Something like:

```
from collections import Counter

result = {}
for key,val in database.items():
    ctr = Counter()
    for gene in val.values():
        ctr.update(gene)
    result[key] = {'genes':dict(ctr)}
```

This gives:

```
>>> result
{'HIV2': {'genes': {'val': 11, 'thr': 10, 'met': 14}},
 'HIV': {'genes': {'val': 5, 'thr': 10, 'met': 12}}}
```

The order of the `HIVn` elements is swapped but note that a dictionary in Python-3.5 has no *inherent* order: the keys can have an arbitrary order.

Comment: @MaximedePachtere: because `dict.update(..)` **overrides** the values. A `Counter.update` **sums up** the values...

Comment: And as always it turns out to be so much easier than the stuff I tried, this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by simply iterating:

```
for d in database:  
    val = 0
    thr = 0
    met = 0
    for gene in database[d]:
        val += database[d][gene]["val"]
        thr += database[d][gene]["thr"]
        met += database[d][gene]["met"]
    database[d] = {}
    database[d]["genes"] = {"val": val, "thr": thr, "met": met}
```

For many fields:

```
result = {}
for d in database:  
    part = {}   
    for gene in database[d]:
        for field in database[d][gene]:
            if field in part:
                part[field] += database[d][gene][field]
            else:
                part[field] = database[d][gene][field]
    result[d] = {"genes": part}
```

Comment: He wants the results written to a new output `database2`.

Comment: Like I said, I have more of everything. There are 20 aminoacids, so that would be a load of lines.